# python3 : Kivy Compile iOS error. No python recipe

Tags: python, ios, python-3.x, kivy

The Error:

```
macbook-MacBook-Pro:test2 macbook$ toolchain create Buttonis ~/Volumes/EFE/test2
[ERROR   ] No python recipe compiled!
[ERROR   ] You must have compiled at least python3
[ERROR   ] recipe to be able to create a project.
```

I want to create a xcodeproj but its not working . Should I build toolchain python2 ? can you help me ?

Answer (score 2):

In short,

> Should I build toolchain python2 ?

Yes. You need to first build the recipes with

```
toolchain build python3 kivy
```

and make sure that that the path `~/Volumes/EFE/test2` exists in your location. Once built, the error should not be reported.

Comment: I still get the same error after doing this.