kivy iOS compile error, [You must have compiled at least python3]
I am trying to use kivy-ios but it doesn’t work for me.  If somebody knows what the problem is, please advise.
My environment is as follows;
Mac : M1
OS: 14.6.1
Python: 3.11.0.
Kivy: 2.3.0.
kivy-ios: 2024.3.17
in virtual environment, I tried blow as written in https://github.com/kivy/kivy-ios
(.venv)$pip3 install kivy-ios.    
(.venv)$xcode-select —install.        
(.venv)$brew install autoconf automake libtool pkg-config.   
(.venv)$brew link libtool.     
(.venv)$toolchain build python3 kivy. 

 

and I get below, seems like I have a problem in building.
STDOUT:    
Makefile:2823: warning: overriding commands for target `Modules/expat/xmlparse.o'.   

Makefile:1031: warning: ignoring old commands for target `Modules/expat/xmlparse.o'.   
   
Makefile:2824: warning: overriding commands for target `Modules/expat/xmlrole.o'.

Makefile:1034: warning: ignoring old commands for target `Modules/expat/xmlrole.o'.    

Makefile:2825: warning: overriding commands for target `Modules/expat/xmltok.o'.     

Makefile:1037: warning: ignoring old commands for target `Modules/expat/xmltok.o'.     

/var/folders/7x/0pf7rsj10zsf800zxpl3psdr0000gn/T/tmp66d021_j -c -Wsign-compare -    Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -O3 -miphoneos-version-min=9.0 -    I/Users/user1/Python/test/dist/include/iphoneos-arm64/ffi -    I/Users/user1/Python/test/dis... (530623 more, please see e.stdout)

STDERR
Then, I tried to create xcode project,
$ toolchain create ABC  /Users/xxx/yyy
 

(/xxx/yyy is the full path to the folder where python source code exists).
but I get below errors.
result is:
[ERROR   ] No python recipe compiled!         
[ERROR   ] You must have compiled at least python3.          
[ERROR   ] recipe to be able to create a project.          

I found same question
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65238343/python3-kivy-compile-ios-error-no-python-recipe].
but it doesn’t help.
It seems like Error says I don’t have python3 but I don’t know what it means and what I should do.
